# Selenium , Python and Chrome Webdriver problem

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning Python and attempting to build a program that will scrape specific data from a website, store it and then manipulate it.

Currently I run my application, it opens a new chrome browser window and loads the page correctly. The problem is it should begin to start scrolling down and loading the remaining elements on the page.

I know the code works because if I manually click somewhere on the page that doesn't normally illicit a response (white space/empty areas) the browser somehow comes into "focus" and begins to iterate through the loop that scrolls down the page (by sending keys) prints the data I am after. I also noticed if I click another similar "dead space" area that contains the header, it doesn't have the same effect. I am unsure if this is something specific to Chrome, iFrames or something of that nature but I am completely stumped and would greatly appreciate any help.

Any thoughts on why I need to manually click on the new chrome window for it to work would be great.

Update: Still having the same issue, even tried with Safari and the same problem seems to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id^='app-container']")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click(on_element = element)
action.perform()
```